# Software to 'lock' computer every half hour

Tags: software-recommendation

I seem to remember seeing some software that limits my computer time, and 'locks' my computer every half hour for five minutes, for example. If I just remembered wrong, is there some sort of software that could do that type of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [brainbreak](http://www.dylanmccall.com/blog/2013/06/23/my-gsoc-2013-project-break-timer-for-gnome/).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brainbreak/daily 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brainbreak
```